# How can i call a spring boot service function in a telegram bot class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, telegram-bot

It's my service class.

```
import dto.NewUser;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public long create(NewUser user) {
        return userRepository.create(new User(user.telegramUserId(),user.firstname(),user.lastname()));
    }
}
```

and this is my telegram bot class.

```
package be.robaws.brootjesbot.bot;

import be.robaws.brootjesbot.services.UserService;
import dto.NewUser;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardRow;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Autowired
    private   UserService userService;

    public Bot(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public Bot(){}
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "myUserName";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "mytoken";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        var user = update.getMessage().getFrom();
        var id = user.getId();
        var msg = update.getMessage();

        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(update.getMessage().getDate());
        ZoneId belgiumZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels");
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, belgiumZone);
        System.out.println(id + ", " + date + ": " + user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName() + ": " + msg.getText());

        if (msg.isCommand()) {
            if (msg.getText().equals("/menu")) {
                try {
                    sendInitialKeyboard(id);
                } catch (TelegramApiException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }

            } **else if (msg.getText().equals("/schrijf_me_in")) {
                NewUser newUser = new NewUser(id, user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName());
                long userId = userService.create(newUser);
            }**
        }

    }

    private void sendInitialKeyboard(Long chatId) throws TelegramApiException {
        ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
        keyboard.setResizeKeyboard(true);
        keyboard.setOneTimeKeyboard(true);
        keyboard.setSelective(true);

        List<KeyboardRow> keyboardRows = new ArrayList<>();
        KeyboardRow row1 = new KeyboardRow();
        row1.add("\uD83E\uDD56 Kies om een broodje te bestellen");
        KeyboardRow row2 = new KeyboardRow();
        row2.add("\uD83D\uDD04 Kies om een bestaande bestelling te vervangen");
        KeyboardRow row3 = new KeyboardRow();
        row3.add("\u274C Kies om een bestaande bestelling te annuleren");
        KeyboardRow row4 = new KeyboardRow();
        row4.add("\uD83D\uDC41️ Kies om uw bestelling te zien");
        KeyboardRow row5 = new KeyboardRow();
        row5.add("\uD83D\uDC41️ Kies om vorige bestellingen te zien");

        keyboardRows.add(row1);
        keyboardRows.add(row2);
        keyboardRows.add(row3);
        keyboardRows.add(row4);
        keyboardRows.add(row5);

        keyboard.setKeyboard(keyboardRows);
        keyboard.setInputFieldPlaceholder("Kies een optie: ");


        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.setChatId(chatId.toString());
        message.setText("Kies een optie: ");
        message.setReplyMarkup(keyboard);


        execute(message);
    }


    public void sendText(Long who, String what) {
        SendMessage sm = SendMessage.builder()
                .chatId(who.toString()) //Who are we sending a message to
                .text(what).build();    //Message content
        try {
            execute(sm);                        //Actually sending the message
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);      //Any error will be printed here
        }
    }


}
```

In my telegramBot class i want to call service.createUser method but if i try that i recieve this fault;

2023-06-22T15:37:37.793+02:00 ERROR 9440 --- [legram Executor] o.t.t.u.DefaultBotSession                : Cannot invoke "be.robaws.brootjesbot.services.UserService.create(dto.NewUser)" because "this.userService" is null

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "be.robaws.brootjesbot.services.UserService.create(dto.NewUser)" because "this.userService" is null
at be.robaws.brootjesbot.bot.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27) ~[telegrambots-meta-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:317) ~[telegrambots-6.0.1.jar:na]

I tried almost everything but i can not create a bean for service. How can i fix it ?

How can i use a spring boot service function in a telegram bot class ?

Comment: Why did you create the default constructor for the `Bot` class? I mean this: `public Bot(){}`